# How do I approximate $f''(x)+(E-U(x))f(x)=0$ for a piecewise $U$ and find $E$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation-theory

I am trying to approximate the solution to the equation

$f''(x)+(E-U(x))f(x)=0$

where 
$U(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{U_0}{m}x-U_0 & \text{for $-m<x<0$} \\
\frac{-U_0}{m}x-U_0 & \text{for $0<x<m$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

using the WKB method.

Assuming that the solution is bounded everywhere, I would then like to find the possible negative values of E.

My attempt (and plans after I got stuck):

When $E>U(x)$, WKB gives

$f\approx \frac{A}{(E-U)^\frac{1}{4}}cos(\int_a^x\sqrt {E-U(x_1)}dx_1-\phi)$

for arbitrary $a$ and constants $A$ and $\phi$, 
and when $E<U(x)$, WKB gives

$f\approx A\frac{1}{(E-U)^\frac{1}{4}}e^{\int_a^x\sqrt {E-U(x_1)}dx_1}+B\frac{1}{(E-U)^\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\int_a^x\sqrt {E-U(x_1)}dx_1}$

for arbitrary $a$ and constants $A$ and $B$.

I want negative E so when $x<-m$ or $x>m$, then $E<U$ and so the first formula applies but when $-m<x<m$, I'm not sure which formula applies as depending on the value of $E$, $E$ could be more or less than $U$ (??).

Anyway, I'm trying to find a formula for $f$ for each of $x<-m$, $-m<x<0$, $0<x<m$ and $x>m$. Then, how do I combine these? Can $f$ be approximated by a piecewise function? Or do I have to look at continuity between the sections?

Then, for the values of E:
I apply the restriction that $f$ is bounded everywhere and hopefully that will lead to a formula for E.

Any ideas or critiques of my ideas?

Comment: You can get an exact solution if you like in terms of Airy functions. Usually how this schrodinger equation is solved

Comment: @TylerHG I haven't come across Airy functions before, care to elaborate? Can you find the possible E values with an approximation or do you need an exact solution?

Comment: @TylerHG I just googled Schrodinger equation and it seems that this question resembles a physics application. I am coming at this problem from a mathematics background and do not really understand the explanations involving particles and energy. Do you have a more "mathy" solution?

Comment: I will work on it my friend and see if I can come up with a Mathy solution for you

Comment: Hi @Ben James: Right now (v1) the potential $U(x)$ is a double well  "$W$", with discontinuities at $x=\pm m$. Is that what you mean? Please double check and confirm.